# Automated Login Will Not Enter Credentials-Prompts Error

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I'm encountering an error when trying to automate the login process for Kronos.  I'm able to get to the site, but it stops short of entering in my credentials.

Have looked thru old code that I have for reference, and tried to find a solution on Stack but have been unable to. I Referenced MS HTML Object Library, MS Internet Controls, & WebServices 1.0 Type Library.

```
  Sub LoginToKronos()

  Const cURL = "https://wikainstruments-sso.prd.mykronos.com/"
  Const cUserID = "firstname.lastname@business.com"
  Const cPassword = "Password123"

  Dim IE As InternetExplorer
  Dim doc As HTMLDocument
  Dim LoginForm As HTMLFormElement
  Dim UsernameInputBox As HTMLInputElement
  Dim SubmitButton As HTMLInputButtonElement
  Dim PasswordInputBox As HTMLInputElement
  Dim LogOnButton As HTMLInputButtonElement

  Set IE = New InternetExplorer

  IE.Visible = True
  IE.navigate cURL

  'Wait for initial page to load

  Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

  Set doc = IE.document

  'Get the only form on the page

  Set LoginForm = doc.forms(0)

  'Get the Username textbox and populate it
  'input name="loginfmt" id="i0116" value="" class="form-control ltr_override" type="email"

  Set UsernameInputBox = doc.getElementById("i0116")
  UsernameInputBox.Value = cUserID

  'Get the form input button and click it

  Set SubmitButton = doc.getElementById("idSIButton9")
  SubmitButton.Click

  'Get the Password textbox and populate it
  'input name="Password" id="passwordInput" class="text fullWidth" type="password"


  Set PasswordInputBox = doc.getElementById("passwordInput")
  PasswordInputBox.Value = cPassword

  'Get the form input button and click it

  Set LogOnButton = doc.getElementById("idSIButton9")
  LogOnButton.Click

  'Wait for the new page to load

  Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

  'avoid any pop up

  End Sub
```

would be nice to get have the credentials populate.

Comment: Can I confirm if this is to login to Workforce Dimensions?

Comment: It is.  The process was recently changed so now it's much more lengthy/time consuming, and requires me to enter credentials every time I want to punch in/out.  The goal is to automate the credential entering process and apply it to a button on my desktop.  One click, and boom, I'm in....in theory.

Comment: https://ath01.prd.mykronos.com/authn/XUI/#login/  will that url suffice?

Comment: I'm not sure that I can change the URL.  I say that because I was using an alternate URL during the transition phase of it's implementation (similar, but different) and my time punches were being recorded but were not visible by HR.  Is there another way to work thru the "RT Error 91" without altering the URL?

Comment: and thanks for the help

Comment: I cannot view your other url. But it may simply be you need a loop until element present. See this example with url I can view and perhaps you can use same approach: https://pastebin.com/9bAy7vqm

Comment: Sorry, got sidetracked with work. I see what you're saying.  I haven't been able to get it to work so far with that, but I'll keep messing with it and see if I can make it work.  In the meantime I'm open to any other helpful suggestions that anyone might have...I realize I just gave a greenlight for any trolls with that statement, but hopefully that won't happen.

Comment: I think it's difficult to help as we don't have access to the website you use. Is there any error throwing when you run the code? You could try to add breakpoints to debug the code. And I'm in favor of what QHarr says, I usually use `Do Until ieA.readyState = 4   DoEvents   Loop` or `Do Until login.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop` after navigating to wait elements to load. You could have a try.

Comment: Completely understand, and I appreciate all the help. I got bogged down with work yesterday and didn't get a chance to mess with it much further so I'm going to try to take another swing at it again today using the above suggestions.  And to your question, I'm getting a 'Run-time Error 91' thrown at the part that is supposed to copy the Username Credentials: UsernameInputBox.Value = cUserID…..Thanks again for the help.

Comment: The error means object variable not set. You could refer to [the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/object-variable-not-set-error-91) about this error to see if you have be caught in the situations or causes mentioned in the doc.

Comment: Hi.  I gave this a look.  It was helpful but I still haven't been able to get the issue resolved.  It's possible that I'm declaring Objects that I shouldn't when I try to fix it or not Setting Objects.  It's not an area that I have a lot of familiarity with.  Currently I'm just a script kiddie (kitty? either or) working my way thru coding so I'll probably need to do a bit more reading up on it..Thanks for the help.